# Creating Instances From Other Instances With Struct

Tags: rust, struct, rust-cargo

```rust
struct User {
    active: bool,
    username: String,
    email: String,
    sign_in_count: u64,
}

fn main() {
    let mut user1 = User {
        active: true,
        username: String::from("someone123"),
        email: String::from("someone@example.com"),
        sign_in_count: 1,
    };

    let user2 = User {
        active: user1.active,
        username: user1.username,
        email: String::from("another@example.com"),
        sign_in_count: user1.sign_in_count,
    };

    let user3 = User {
        active: user1.active,
        username: user1.username, // I got error in this line
        email: String::from("another@example.com"),
        sign_in_count: user1.sign_in_count,
    };
}
```

I newbie in Rust. I just want to create new struct's instances dependent on `user1` instance. but I got this error:

```
use of moved value: `user1.username`
move occurs because `user1.username` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` traitrustcE0382
main.rs(18, 19): value moved here
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String`s can't be copied in Rust, they can only be cloned.

When you initialize your struct fields from another struct's fields, Rust tries to either copy or move those fields. It doesn't attempt to clone them.

When you write `username: user1.username`, you are moving the `username` out of `user1`, since it can't be copied. Doing that twice is not allowed. A `String` can only be owned by one party, and your code attempts make it owned by both `user2` and `user3`.

Here's a working solution that may be a little more concise, too:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct User {
    active: bool,
    username: String,
    email: String,
    sign_in_count: u64,
}

fn main() {
    let mut user1 = User {
        active: true,
        username: String::from("someone123"),
        email: String::from("someone@example.com"),
        sign_in_count: 1,
    };

    let user2 = User {
        email: String::from("another@example.com"),
        ..user1.clone()
    };

    let user3 = User {
        email: String::from("another@example.com"),
        ..user1.clone()
    };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cf9ff45b6a4ad8efa42d702d262de54c)